# in Android replace ListView Fragment with Details Fragment on item click

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I've got a database search function working in a `Fragment`. Now I want the search Fragment to get replaced with the details Fragment when the user clicks an item in the search results list. It's my understanding that a Fragment Transaction can't be initiated in a Fragment, so what I've done is sub classed the Fragment in the Main Activity Class, and everything works fine, up until you want to click an item in the search results. My minimum API is 10, so I'm using the support library, and when I try and set up the Transaction in the `setOnClickListener()` by doing this: `FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` I get the warning: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSupportFragmentManager() from the type FragmentActivity`. **So How can I replace my search Fragment with the details Fragment in the `setOnClickListener()`?** Here's what I've got:

```
public class SearchInterface extends ActionBarActivity {
ActionBar bar_AB;
private static EditText searchbox_ET;
private static DBAdapter dbHelper;
static View searchRootView;
static ListView listView_LV;
String searchResultStr;
static Cursor getPathCursor;
static String cursorSDFStr = null;
static String cursorCalDateStr = null;
static String cursorURLStr = null;
static String cursorTitleStr = null;
static String cursorinfoBodyStr = null;

String videoURLStr = null;
String sdfStr = null;
String calDateStr = null;
String titleStr = null;
String infoBodyStr = null;

static FragmentManager fragMan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

    // --- set up Action Bar
    bar_AB = getSupportActionBar();
    bar_AB.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragMan.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        SSISearchFragEm searchEm_FRG = new SSISearchFragEm();
        fragMan.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, searchEm_FRG)
                .commit();
    }

}// --- END onCreate

public static class SSISearchFragEm extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout list_LL;
    private Button search_BTN;

    // --- Create the ROOT VIEW
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        searchRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ssi_search_frag,
                container, false);
        searchbox_ET = (EditText) searchRootView
                .findViewById(R.id.ssi_Search1_et1);
        search_BTN = (Button) searchRootView
                .findViewById(R.id.ssi_search_btn1);
        list_LL = (LinearLayout) searchRootView
                .findViewById(R.id.ssi_search_list_LL);

        // --- Button
        search_BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
                dbHelper.open();
                String searchTermStr = searchbox_ET.getText().toString();
                Cursor cursor = dbHelper.searchDB(searchTermStr);

                if (cursor != null) {
                    String[] columns = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
                            DBAdapter.KEY_CAL_DATE, DBAdapter.KEY_PATH,
                            DBAdapter.KEY_SDF, DBAdapter.KEY_INFOBODY,
                            DBAdapter.KEY_KEYWORDS };

                    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.slp_title_tv, R.id.slp_date_tv,
                            R.id.slp_url_tv, R.id.slp_sdf_tv, R.id.slp_infoBody_tv,
                            R.id.slp_keywords_tv };

                    SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                            getActivity(), R.layout.slp_list_item, cursor, columns, to,
                            0);

                    listView_LV = (ListView) searchRootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ssisearch_list_lv);
                    listView_LV.setEmptyView(searchRootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ssiempty_list_tv));
                    listView_LV.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                }                   
                dbHelper.close();
                //--- onClick

                // --- pass to ListVideo
                listView_LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        getPathCursor = (Cursor) listView_LV
                                .getItemAtPosition(position);
                        cursorSDFStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("sdfdate"));
                        cursorCalDateStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("caldate"));
                        cursorURLStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("path"));
                        cursorTitleStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
                        cursorinfoBodyStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("details"));
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item Be Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //--- Detail fragment here?
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


                    }

                });//--- END onClick

            }
        });
        // --- END Button

        return searchRootView;
    }// --- END Create the ROOT VIEW



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. @jitain sharma set me on the right path, even though I found that `getChildFragmentManager()` was not my solution. Here's my solution:

```
fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
listFrag = fragMan.findFragmentByTag("com.myapp.SearchFragEm");
if(listFrag != null)fragTrans.remove(listFrag);
video_FRG = new SSIVideoFrag();
fragTrans.replace(R.id.frag5_main_FL, video_FRG);
fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
fragTrans.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.graph_layout, checkUpGraphFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Add some description to why this is the solution to the problem. Right now the answer is of very low quality.

Comment: I think this solution might work, except that I'm getting an error about the BackStackRecord `java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)`